# How can I configure my ADSL2+ modem to tunnel all the traffic through a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel, adsl-router, adsl2+

I know about SSH tunneling and I always do it (to a remote SSH server) using PuTTY (or `ssh -D` when I'm on Linux) to stay anonymous while web surfing (i.e. by setting my browser's proxy settings to connect to PuTTY's SOCKS5 proxy).

Now I want to somehow configure my ADSL2+ modem to do this, so that all the devices connected to the modem (such as my TV, my Android phone, google home, etc.) enjoy this anonymity (i.e. so that all of them have the same IP address as my "remote SSH server") and besides I won't have to change my browser's proxy settings anymore.

How can I do that? And what type of modem do I need?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Easier solution, connect modem to Linux server, and then use the server as a router that’s acts like a proxy your modem is unlikely to support what you want directly

Comment: I didn't understand your solution. My end goal is to have internet anonymity on my phone when connected to home WiFi. Will your solution achieve that? If yes, then please explain in more details. Thanks.

Comment: I gave you more then enough to get started.  Can’t help you with your phone issues since it’s sligh out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

If your ADSL2+ modem is typical, you can't do this - you will need an intermediate router to make this possible.

That said, using SSH is not a great tool for the job.  I would recommend getting a basic router which supports DD-WRT, and then setting OpenVPN up on your server, and your router as an OpenVPN client, to route all your traffic across OpenVPN.